# BigQuery data model for nearest places by travel time

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a following requirement and new to BigQuery.

Requirement,

We have bunch of stores and there are competitor stores as well. 
  When i choose a competitor store and travel time( Say, within 15mins, within 30mins, within 45mins, within 60mins), it has to return our store within the selected travel time. Here, travel time is based on the standard time not based on traffic and we will have only 4 options(15, 30, 45, 60).

My data model based on my knowledge,

```
**competitor_store_id | traveltime | stores(comma_separated)**

  Example Data,

C1 | 15 | S1,S2,S3,S4,S5  ---> Here there are 5 stores with in 15 mins
C2 | 30 | S6,S7,S8,S9,S10  --> Here there are 10 stores within 30 mins travel time. So storing delta b/w 15 mins and 30 mins, so the data will be 15mins+30mins for 30 mins traveltime
```

Is there any better approach?

**Sample Request:-**

```
stores/C1?time=15
```

**Output:-**

```
S1,S2,S3,S4,S5
```

**Sample Request:-**

```
stores/C1?time=30
```

**Output:-**

```
S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10
```

Comment: Can you post a sample output so it is easier to understand the logic? Also, you mention that  in the 2nd row of data that there are 10 stores there, whereas the data just shows 5 elements. Can you explain this to me ?

Comment: 2nd row will just have delta. under 15 mins we have 5 stores. Under 30 mins, we have totally 10 stored which includes under 15 mins store as well. Hence storing the delta alone in under 30 mins,

Comment: Could you post sample data and expected output from this sample data ? It would be easier to understand the logic and propose a solution.

Comment: Updated with Sample.

Answer (score 1):

After you uploaded your sample request and output, I understood you wanted a query to create a view with the sample request and output you shared. Thus, I was able to come up with a helpful query. I have used the following sample data, in order to replicate your case.

```
WITH data as (
SELECT "C1" as competitor_store_id, 15 AS traveltime, "S1,S2,S3,S4,S5" as stores UNION ALL
SELECT "C1" as competitor_store_id, 30 AS traveltime, "S6,S7,S8,S9,S10" as stores UNION ALL
SELECT "C2" as competitor_store_id, 15 AS traveltime, "S1,S2,S3,S4,S5" as stores UNION ALL
SELECT "C2" as competitor_store_id, 30 AS traveltime, "S6,S7" as stores UNION ALL
SELECT "C2" as competitor_store_id, 45 AS traveltime, "S8" as stores 
)
```

Using the [STRING_AGG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg) method, and the query is as below:

```
select competitor_store_id, STRING_AGG(stores) as stores from data 
where traveltime <= 30
group by 1
```

And the output,

[image]

Therefore, you will be able to select the stores within a range of time for each `competitor_store_id`. In the above example I used 30 as `traveltime`. So, as you can see, in the output it is not shown **S8** for C2(`competitor_store_id`) at 45 as `traveltime`. Whereas, for C1 all 10 stores were listed.